# I get a permission denied error in account

Tags: permissions, cron

new time poster here.

So I have discovered the potential of crontab (I installed Linux in May, so a new guy when it comes to Linux, but I have gotten used to it and started using themes about a week ago) today, and after reading a tutorial decided it useful for my workflow and have had trouble saving it. I got a `permission denied` error when trying to save it in /var/spool/cron/crontabs/.

The full error was 
`[Error writing /var/spool/cron/crontabs/cronstuff: Permission Denied]` after trying to save a document in the built-in editor with terminal (forgot which one but know I selected the first option after being prompted to chose an editor to make the crontab document with.)

EDIT: I get the same error saving to /etc/cron.hourly/cronstuff.

Sequence up to error: `crontab -e`, add info I want it to do, Ctrl O, rename file to `/var/spool/cron/crontabs/cronstuff`, yes, I want to save the file as a different name, `[Error writing /var/spool/cron/crontabs/cronstuff: Permission Denied]`

Any help here?

thanks

Comment: *How* did you try to save the file? what sequence of steps or commands led up to the error?

Comment: The cron setup is in `/etc/crontab` (or just put your script in `/etc/cron.{hourly|saily|weekly|monthly}`). "Permission" denied is not always a matter of access rights, another process may have the file open in exclusive write. You can check with `lsof`.

Comment: edited for clarifacation

Comment: Ubuntu does not have a root account (by default).  What version and flavor of Ubuntu are you using?  How are you certain that you are using the root account?

Comment: I downloaded the OS on my computer recently and my account was the only one until i added a guest account recently. No flavors, pure Ubuntu, 20.04. sorry i pressed enter too soon @Nmath

Comment: you shouldn't have a root account then.  I suggest trying commands starting with `sudo` under your main user.

Comment: It worked, but I can't seem to see it with `sudo crontab -l` @Nmath

Comment: The problem is that you are renaming the crontab file. Stop that. Let the crontab application do it's job.

Answer (score 2):

The normal way to create a crontab file that automatically is placed in the `/var/spool/cron/crontabs/` directory is by invoking the command `crontab -e`. Then a file is created in that directory with the same name as your username. From the error message it seems to me that you tried to save the file with the name `cronstuff` or maybe invoked the editor with `crontab -e cronstuff`. The system then looks for a user with the name `cronstuff`and refuses to save the file as there is no such user.

You need to be root when placing a crontab file for another user but not to place one for yourself. If you want to create a crontab file that is not meant for a user then, as root, create a crontab file with (almost) any name and place it in `/etc/cron.d, /etc/cron.daily/, /etc/cron.monthly/, /etc/cron.weekly/` or `/etc/cron.hourly/` depending on its use. See [the crontab howto](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto) at Ubuntu documentation pages.

Comment: the crontab -e would save the file as `/tmp/crontab.rUUwgq/crontab` if I didn't edit it. Got same error when trying to save as `/etc/cron.hourly/crontab` as well.

Comment: @wall03 it would only save the file as `/tmp/crontab.rUUwgq/crontab` briefly, before immediately writing the edited file to `/var/spool/cron/crontabs/<username>`